# How to reduce audio delay in FFmpeg using HTTP FLV stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, frame-rate, rtmp, flv

I have problem with live http flv stream. I'm using the following command and it works great except for the audio. Audio has delay that increasing over time. I can fix the this by removing refresh rate option on the output (-r 30) but then stream latency goes higher for about half second.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -threads 0 -video_size 672X420 -i /dev/video1 -f alsa -thread_queue_size 512 -i hw:1,0 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -s 672x420 -r 30 -g 60 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/primary
```

Can someone explain why this happening and what possible fixes are?
On the client I'm using Chrome with flv.js library.
On the server Node-Media-Server.